# HLSL cbuffer equivalent in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, hlsl

HLSL has the `cbuffer` type that can be used for look-up-tables.

What is the equivalent for `cbuffer`s in OpenGL? What's the recommended way to store lookup tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent functionality to a "cbuffer" in GLSL is a [uniform interface block](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_%28GLSL%29), who's data comes from a [buffer object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object). The totality of the concept is called a "[Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object)". Though unlike D3D, OpenGL does not mark these buffers as being any different from any other kind of buffer object. So you could use the same buffer object for storing uniforms and for vertex data, or (more usefully) as the output of a transform feedback operation. Or whatever.

A uniform block is declared in a shader a bit like HLSL cbuffers, but in a GLSL style:

```
uniform BlockName
{
  vec4 someVariable;
} optionalInstanceName;
```

While UBOs are an OpenGL 3.1 feature, you need to be using OpenGL 4.2 or ARB_shading_language_420pack if you want to be able to associate the block with a binding index in the shader:

```
//BlockName uses binding point 0.
layout(binding = 0) uniform BlockName
{
  vec4 someVariable;
} optionalInstanceName;
```

Without this functionality, you must use `glUniformBlockBinding​` to manually set the binding point for the block named `BlockName`. Though first you have to query the index of that block with `glGetUniformBlockIndex​`. But once it's set, it's part of the program object's state, so you don't need to set it more than once.

In any case, I wouldn't characterize UBOs or cbuffers as being for "look-up-tables". Particularly in HLSL, where "cbuffer"s are the primary way to get uniform data to a shader.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, I have to create a buffer with `glGenBuffers()` and fill in the correct bytes. Afterwards, I can use `glUniformBlockBinding()` to assign the generated buffer to my uniform block. Can I assume that floats and other datatypes have the same bit-level representation as on my CPU, since I can only assign bytes to VOBs?

Comment: Does this also apply to a "tbuffer" not just "cbuffer" in GLSL?

Comment: @zezba9000: No. The OpenGL equivalent to a "tbuffer" is a [buffer texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture).

Comment: I mean how can you define a "tbuffer" in GLSL?  I know its just a texture BUT how can you define them in GLSL so you can use them for a float4x4 array like you can in HLSL for example?

Comment: @zezba9000: GLSL doesn't have the syntactic sugar D3D10 has for its "tbuffers". A buffer texture is a means of accessing formatted data through a texture access. There's no sugar to allow you to pretend that these accesses are accessing a struct or something.

Comment: So you're saying in GLSL I would have to manually sample 4 float4's using "texelFetch" to build a float4x4?  If so that makes sense. Thanks, just making sure I'm not missing something silly.